# Can faulty relays cause fluctuating run performance or will they either be on, off or intermittent?

Tags: diagnostics, relay

Car is experiencing reduced performance as well as stalling.  Assuming these are caused by the same issue is it fair to say it cannot be a relay.

Reason is because, as far as I’m aware, a main relay will either be on, off or intermittent by virtue of being a switch and do not determine amount of voltage delivered etc.  therefore it they cannot be causing reduced/fluctuating performance issues such as a fuel pump receiving less power.

Just want to ensue don’t waste my time looking at relays for fluctuating or reduced performance issues.

Thanks.

Comment: Coukd you clarify the question title into English?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you keep barking up these trees you do? Normal relays are either energized or not. If energized, they have continuity between the posts which you'd expect, which would allow electricity to pass through. They are a VERY simple device which has been around for a long time. They allow a low amperage circuit to pass a higher load through, which allows switches to work without burning out. Not much there to change how a car runs.